# file_get_content() function won't work in WordPress shortcode function

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have written this shortcode for WordPress and am pretty sure the problem is my weak PHP knowledge.

When I `return $full_liveshot_url_fetch` the function comes out perfectly with the shortcode and I get the full URL, but when I add the function `get_file_content()` to return the page it fails and I get the warning: **file_get_contents("xxx xxxx xxxx.....): failed to open stream:**

When I do the same thing outside the function it works...

```php
function live_shot_code($markup) {  //just to checheck that a url is filled out and set a default
    if(!isset($markup['url'])) $markup['url'] = 'http://itmastersworld.com/liveshot/nothingset/';

    $full_liveshot_url_fetch = '"http://itmastersworld.com/liveshot/getImage.php?url='.$markup['url'].'&title='.$markup['title'].'&width='.$markup['width'].'&height='.$markup['height'].'&quality='.$markup['quality'].'&zoom='.$markup['zoom'].'"';
    $done_getting = file_get_contents($full_liveshot_url_fetch);
    return $done_getting;
}
add_shortcode('wpliveshot', 'live_shot_code');
```

Comment: Why do you have single and double quotes surrounding the url? The double quotes will now end up in your url, making it invalid.

Comment: how should i do it, i mean i was trying to construct the string without breaking php

Comment: when i echo the url it comes out fine

Comment: Hold on, @ontrack you are very right, i tried it and now works , than k you so much